# How do I force all Tree itemrenderers to refresh?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tree

I have item renderers in an mx.controls.Tree that I need to refresh on demand.

I have code in the updateDisplayList that fires for only some of the visible nodes no matter what I do. I've tried triggering a change that they should all be listening for; I have tried clearing and resetting the dataProvider and the itemRenderer properties.

```
        private function forceCategoryTreeRefresh(event : Event = null) : void
        {
            trace("forceCategoryTreeRefresh");

            var prevDataProvider : Object = CategoryTree.dataProvider;
            CategoryTree.dataProvider = null;
            CategoryTree.validateNow();
            CategoryTree.dataProvider = prevDataProvider;

            var prevItemRenderer : IFactory = CategoryTree.itemRenderer;
            CategoryTree.itemRenderer = null;

            CategoryTree.itemRenderer = prevItemRenderer as IFactory;

            _categoriesChangeDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE));
        }
```

The nodes refresh properly when I scroll them into view (e.g. the .data gets set), but I cannot force the ones that already exist to refresh or reset themselves.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling this function on change event:

```
private function refreshList(e:Event):void{
          listName.invalidateSize();
          listName.invalidateList();
          listName.invalidateDisplayList();
          listName.validateSize(true);
          listName.validateNow();
        }
```

for me work quite well

Answer (score 0):

Try
`treeView.dataProvider = treeView.dataProvider;`

That should update Tree view.

Answer (score -1):

ItemRenderers in Flex are virtualized so there will not always be one ItemRenderer for each Tree node.

However, you can invalidate the nodes to force a refresh.  The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390637/force-all-item-renderers-to-commitproperties) gives an example of how to do that.